# How to make a rotation and then stop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, rotation

I got a div to start rotating, but I am not sure how to make it stop at an angle. At the moment all that is happing is that it keeps going. My question is how do i get it to stop at an angle like 96.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
var $elie = $("#super");
rotate(1);
function rotate(degree) {        
    $elie.css({ WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});  
    $elie.css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});                      
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
     rotate(++degree);
    },2);
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: If you set the timer delay to 2 (ms) you will kill the performance. Set it to the value in range 16 - 40ms (25-60 fps).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To stop at 96 degress, try this:

```
if (degree < 96) {
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        rotate(++degree);
    }, 2);
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/XYcAB/)

Comment: @ktamlyn Good point abot hitting 97 - I've fixed that. As for fitting in a functional manner, I'm not sure what you mean. The `rotate` function won't be called again after 96 is hit therefore the timeout will never be instantiated again.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var stopAtValue = 96;

$(function() {
var $elie = $("#super");
rotate(1);
function rotate(degree) {        
    $elie.css({ WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});  
    $elie.css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});                      
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
    if(degree==stopAtValue) {
      // do nothing
    } else {
      rotate(++degree);
    },2);
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: While this will work, it's not good to continually call the `rotate` function every two ms with the same value.